# Unexpected AST node exception when using subquery inside case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa, criteria, predicate

I have two tables Project and cod. A project can have multiple cod of different types like creative, distributive etc. Now i want to fetch all the projects joined with their first record on cod having cod type creative and if the project does not have any cod of creative type then bring the joined result of project with first entry in cod table for that project of any different type or if there are no cod then bring with cod null. I have created the sql query  . Its like

```
SELECT 
  p.PROJECT_ID           
  FROM PROJECT p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN cod c1 ON p.PROJECT_ID=c.PROJECT_ID
  WHERE p.DEPARTMENT_ID = 1
  AND (c.cod_id = (CASE WHEN  ((SELECT MIN(c.cod_id)
                                                        FROM cod c 
                                                        WHERE c.name='Creative'
                                                      ) ) IS not NULL 
                                                      THEN 
                                                     (SELECT MIN(c.cod_id)
                                                        FROM cod c 
                                                        WHERE c.name='Creative'
                                                     )
                                              Else
                                                      (SELECT MIN(c.cod_id)
                                                        FROM cod c 
                                                        WHERE c.name!='Creative'
                                                     )
                                            END
                                            ) 
        OR c.cod_id IS NULL     
      ) ;
```

now i want to achieve through jpa criteria builder and predicates but that is throwing

```
17:55:10,748 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
17:55:10,748 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-1) <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query: <AST>:0:0: unexpected AST node: query
```

I am not able to find out the cause of that.

Comment: Well, since you've only shown us something that already works, I can't see how we could be of assistance. In any case, I don't think JPA Criteria API/JPQL supports subqueries in the `THEN` part of the `CASE` statement. You could try using `CriteriaBuilder.coalesce()` with subqueries obtained from `CriteriaBuilder.subquery()` as parameters instead

Comment: Coalesce worked like charm. Thanks.